# Is "I am writing to inform you" awkward or outdated?

Tags: phrases, email, letter-writing

I was writing an email, and I started off with

> I am writing to inform you of certain errors...

However, is this use outdated or awkward in emails (assuming that I don't know the recipient)? What about formal correspondence (e.g. letters)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't believe it outdated, but very much reserved to:

- [business letter](http://esl.about.com/cs/onthejobenglish/a/a_basbletter.htm) (where it is one of the [common phrases](http://www.eslgold.com/business/letters_phrases.html): "`I am writing to inquire about ...`")
- [application letter](http://158.132.164.193/ELSC/material/Writing/appln.htm) ("`I am writing to apply for the position of ...`")

Some [guide on writing style](http://www.wikihow.com/Avoid-Colloquial-%28Informal%29-Writing) will advise you to:

> Avoid stage directions.
>   Do not commence a letter by telling the recipient what you plan to do in the letter or begin an essay by telling the reader what the paper will discuss.
>
> "`I am writing to you to ask you to ...`"
>    "`This paper is going to talk about how ...`"

So if you only want to express the intent in a less formal way, a simple "**`I would like to inform you of ...`**" is enough.

Comment: Don't forget recommendation letters.

Answer (score 5):

As VonC at least implies, the basic construct is somewhat formal. But I think *"I am writing..."* is slightly informal by comparison with *"I write..."* - so for me, it sits uneasily with the more formal *"...to inform you..."*

Interestingly, Google Books bears this point out. The informal version of *"...to inform you..."* is *"...to let you know..."*; it turns out the pairing *"I am writing to let you know..."* (both informal) is much more common than *"I write to let you know..."* (mixed formal/informal) by [8,840](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I%20write%20to%20inform%20you%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22I%20am%20writing%20to%20let%20you%20know%22&oq=%22I%20am%20writing%20to%20let%20you%20know%22&gs_l=serp.3...8992.13123.0.13435.15.15.0.0.0.0.215.1017.14j0j1.15.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.c1mW-OHA4Xc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=70f0bff01af8d7b0&biw=1421&bih=739) to [5,960](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I%20write%20to%20inform%20you%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22I%20write%20to%20let%20you%20know%22&oq=%22I%20write%20to%20let%20you%20know%22&gs_l=serp.3...230688.230688.0.231296.1.1.0.0.0.0.65.65.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.BM1husMKEGc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43148975,d.d2k&fp=70f0bff01af8d7b0&biw=1421&bih=739).

On the other hand *"I write to inform you..."* (both "formal") is in fact **more common** (by [17,900](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I%20write%20to%20inform%20you%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) to [14,000](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I%20write%20to%20inform%20you%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22I%20am%20writing%20to%20inform%20you%22&oq=%22I%20am%20writing%20to%20inform%20you%22&gs_l=serp.3...2484.6990.0.7317.7.7.0.0.0.0.86.376.7.7.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.wyVbKZrKzns&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43148975,d.d2k&fp=70f0bff01af8d7b0&biw=1421&bih=739)) than OP's (mixed informal/formal) *"I am writing to inform you..."*.

---

Personally, I think the formula doesn't have much to commend it. What's the point in starting a written communication with *I write* or *I am writing*? Obviously you are - in the fullness of time they'll be *reading* what you wrote, so they know that. And do they really need to be told that you're *going to tell them* something? Just get on and *actually* tell them whatever it is you want to say.

Answer (score 4):

It is clearly redundant and circumspect. However, it sounds polite, and some situations do call for social niceties.

> I am writing to inform you that I'm writing to inform you that I'm writing to inform you of certain errors.

vs.

> Please address the following errors:

If I were to act on the information, I'd prefer the more direct style.